# No permission to create files when running with AppEngineRun after migration from Appengine SDK to Cloud SDK

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sdk

I'm dealing with a problem after a recent migration from AppEngine SDK to Cloud SDK. While running with the gradle task AppEngineRun I'm not being able to create/read files due a permission denied exception (IO Exception).

```
File file = new File("test");
if(!file.exists()) {
    directory.mkdir();
}
```

But I'm able to create/read files if I create a mock main inside the project and run it as a NO-APPEGINE-APP

**Edit**
I'm using Standard environment, the like is normally saved at the root of project when I still using AppEngine SDK

Comment: Standard env? Is the in your app dir?

Comment: I've edited my comment. I'm Using APP Engine Standard Environment. The file, when I'm using AppEngine SDK is being saved on the root of the project.

Comment: The standard env sandbox doesn't normally allow writing to the application directory (on GAE, not on the local environment) so maybe the new SDK attempts to emulate that locally as well for the application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying the runtime environment solved the problem

`<runtime>java8</runtime>/`

Though I'm not sure about the reason. I just made a long shot.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the web application directory, you may choose to use another directory, different from the default one, using the convention property warDir: *"appengineRun: Starts a local development server running your project code. By default the WAR file is created, exploded and used as web application directory each time you run this task. This behavior can be changed by setting the convention property warDir"*. 
More details can be gathered from the [Gradle App Engine plugin](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin). 
For data storage, your are advised to use rather Cloud Datastore, Cloud SQL, Memcache, or Cloud Storage, as the local file system is not accessible in the cloud environment.